# Apache Mahout not giving any recommendation

Tags: java, dictionary, machine-learning, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am trying to use mahout for the recommendation **but getting none**.

My dataset :

```
0,102,5.0
1,101,5.0
1,102,5.0
```

Code :

```
      DataModel datamodel = new FileDataModel(new File("dataset.csv"));
        // Creating UserSimilarity object.
        UserSimilarity usersimilarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(datamodel);

        // Creating UserNeighbourHHood object.
        UserNeighborhood userneighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, usersimilarity, datamodel);

        // Create UserRecomender
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(datamodel, userneighborhood, usersimilarity);

        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(0, 1);

        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
            System.out.println(recommendation);
        }
```

**I am using Mahout version : 0.13.0**

Ideally, it should recommend `item_id = 101' to 'user_id = 0' as`user = 0`and`user = 1`have item 102   common show it should recommend`item_id = 101`to`user_id = 0`

Logs :

```
18:08:11.669 [main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Creating FileDataModel for file dataset.csv
18:08:11.700 [main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Reading file info...
18:08:11.702 [main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Read lines: 3
18:08:11.722 [main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.GenericDataModel - Processed 2 users
18:08:11.738 [main] DEBUG org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender - Recommending items for user ID '0'
```

Comment: Is Scala/v0.13.0 an option? v 0.10 is pretty out of date. (0.13.0 dropped last night).

Comment: sure trying with v0.13

Comment: no luck, still getting nothing

Answer (score 3):

The Hadoop Mapreduce code in Mahout is being deprecated. The new recommender code starts with @rawkintrevo 's examples. If you are a Scala programmer follow them.

Most Engineers would like a system that works with no modification, The Mahout algorithm is encapsulated in The Universal Recommender built on top of Apache PredictionIO. It has a server to accept events, like the ones in your example, it has internal event storage, and a query server for results. There are numerous improvements over the old Mapreduce code, including using real-time user behavior to make recommendations. Neither the new Mahout nor the old included servers for input and query, the Universal Recommender has REST endpoints for both.

Given that the code you are using will be deprecated I strongly suggest that you dive into Mahout code (@rawkintrevo's example) or look at The Universal Recommender, which is an entire end-to-end system.

- Install PredictionIO with a "single machine" setup [here](http://actionml.com/docs/single_machine) or to really shortcut setup use our prepackaged AWS AMI [here](http://actionml.com/docs/awssetupguide) It includes PIO and The Universal Recommender pre-installed.
- Add the UR Template [here](http://actionml.com/docs/ur_quickstart)
- A Java SDK for sending events to the recommender [here](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/sdk/java/)

Once you have this setup you deal with config, REST or Java SDK and the PIO CLI. No Scala coding required.

Comment: is prediction Io next version of mahout

Comment: No, 0.13.1 is. PredictionIO has the universal recommender which in turn is an end to end pipeline.

Since you weren't able to get the simple example running, pat is suggesting you try using something a little more turn key.

Answer (score 2):

I have three examples that are based on version 0.13.0 (and Scala, which is required for Samsara, the R-Like Scala DSL Mahout utilizes v0.10+)

**Walk**

The first example is a very slow walk through:
https://gist.github.com/rawkintrevo/3869030ff1a731d43c5e77979a5bf4a8
and is meant as a companion to Pat Ferrels blog post/slide deck found here.
http://actionml.com/blog/cco

**Crawl**

The second example is a little more "real" in that it utilizes the `SimilarityAnalysis.cooccurrencesIDSs(...` which is the propper interface for the CCO algorithm.

https://gist.github.com/rawkintrevo/c1bb00896263bdc067ddcd8299f4794c

**Run**

Here we use 'real' data. The MovieLens data set doesn't have enough going on to showcase CCO's multi-modal power (the ability to recommend on multiple user behaviors).  Here we load 'real' data and generate recommendations.
https://gist.github.com/rawkintrevo/f87cc89f4d337d7ffea80a6af3bee83e

**Conclusion**
I know you specifically asked for Java, however Apache Mahout isn't geared for Java at the moment. In theory you could import Scala into your java, or maybe wrap the functions in another more Java friendly function... I've heard rumors late at night (or possibly in a dream) that some grad students some where were working on a Java API, but its not in the trunk at the moment, nor is there a PR, nor is their a bullet in the road map.

Hope the above provides some insight.

**Appendix**

The most trivial example for Stackoverflow (you can run this interactively in the Mahout spark shell by typing `$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout spark-shell` (assuming `SPARK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `MAHOUT_HOME` are set):

```
val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(  ("u1", "purchase",    "iphone"),
  ("u1","purchase","ipad"),
  ("u2","purchase","nexus"),
  ("u2","purchase","galaxy"),
  ("u3","purchase","surface"),
  ("u4","purchase","iphone"),
  ("u4","purchase","galaxy"),
  ("u1","category-browse","phones"),
  ("u1","category-browse","electronics"),
  ("u1","category-browse","service"),
  ("u2","category-browse","accessories"),
  ("u2","category-browse","tablets"),
  ("u3","category-browse","accessories"),
  ("u3","category-browse","service"),
  ("u4","category-browse","phones"),
  ("u4","category-browse","tablets")) )



import org.apache.mahout.math.indexeddataset.{IndexedDataset, BiDictionary}
import org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.indexeddataset.IndexedDatasetSpark

val purchasesIDS = IndexedDatasetSpark.apply(inputRDD.filter(_._2 == "purchase").map(o => (o._1, o._3)))(sc)
val browseIDS = IndexedDatasetSpark.apply(inputRDD.filter(_._2 == "category-browse").map(o => (o._1, o._3)))(sc)

import org.apache.mahout.math.cf.SimilarityAnalysis

val llrDrmList = SimilarityAnalysis.cooccurrencesIDSs(Array(purchasesIDS, browseIDS),
  randomSeed = 1234,
  maxInterestingItemsPerThing = 3,
  maxNumInteractions = 4)

val llrAtA = llrDrmList(0).matrix.collect
```

`IndexedDatasetSpark.apply(` requires an `RDD[(String, String)]` where the first string is the 'row' (e.g. users), second string is the 'behavior' so for the 'buy matrix', the columns would be 'products', but this could also be a 'gender' matrix, with two columns (male/female)

Then you pass an array of IndexedDataSets to `SimilarityAnalysis.cooccurrencesIDSs(`

Comment: That very cool, but could you please help me for my above data set. Java and scala are similar, it won't be difficult if you give example in either language.

But the problem is that for some dataset I am getting outputs and for some datasets not. So that's Why I posted really simple data set.

Comment: can you describe your dataset? 
Is it userID,action,productiD?

Comment: It's userId,productId,preferenceValue

Comment: see pat's answer but try refactoring your input to userID, action, productID

Comment: I am amazed why this very simple use case didn't worked with Mahout