# Apache Mahout Recommender not working

Tags: apache, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am using Apache Mahout Library for Recommendation but I fail to understand its working as it works for some of my cases and doesn't work for others.
I a using Apache Mahout 0.12.2 version in Java 8.

Code

```
public class SampleRecommender {

public static void main(String[] ars) throws IOException, TasteException
{
    DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(new File("E:\\Rakshit\\Recommender\\stackdata.csv"));
    UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, dataModel);
    UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(dataModel, neighborhood, similarity);

    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(3,3);

    for(RecommendedItem item : recommendations)
    {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

}

For Example for the following data it does not work

```
3,101,5.0
3,102,5.0
3,104,5.0
4,102,2.0
4,104,4.0
4,105,2.5
4,107,3.0
5,101,5.0
5,102,5.0
5,104,5.0
5,105,4.0
```

While for this data it works

```
3,101,5.0
3,102,2.0
3,105,2.5
4,102,2.0
4,104,4.0
4,105,2.5
4,107,3.0
5,101,5.0
5,102,3.4
5,104,2.5
5,105,2.5
```

Output

```
RecommendedItem[item:104, value:3.3029697]
```

The difference in the two data is in the rating values of userID 3 and userID 5

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm happy to help, but this is a very poorly formed question. I'm not going to downvote yet, but we need a lot of information about what you've done, code, CLI driver? Mahout Version? Spark Version? etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Mahout code you are using will be deprecated soon. However Mahout has a newer better version. Answers are on a similar question here:

[Apache Mahout not giving any recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472237/apache-mahout-not-giving-any-recommendation/43499578#43499578)